# Rails Admin config.authorize_with redirect user if not admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-admin

I have a Rails 3.2.x app using the `rails_admin` gem on the back end.  I'm also using Devise for authentication and have a role field on the `User` model to say whether or not the user is an admin or employee.

What I'm trying to do is setup an authorization for rails_admin so if you visit http://domain.com/admin it will only allow it if the `current_user.role == "admin"` otherwise redirect to my home controller index path `home_index_path`

I've setup an initializer that should do this, and it does deny admin access if the role is not admin, but I get the following error: `No route matches {:controller=>"home"}`.  I'm thinking it might have to do with the `routes.rb` and where I have the RailsAdmin line mounted in `routes.rb` but am not sure.  Ultimately this should check the role to make sure it's equal to admin if not, redirect_to home_index_path and flash a message.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**rails_admin.rb**

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with do |controller|
    unless current_user.role == 'admin'
      flash[:error] = "You are not an admin"
      redirect_to home_index_path
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some google searching I found an [issue](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1207) that addresses this.  It looks like the namespace is different so redirecting to `main_app.root_path did the trick.  I still cannot get the flash message to work.  Any thoughts on this?

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with do |controller|
    unless current_user.role == 'admin'
      redirect_to main_app.root_path
      flash[:error] = "You are not an admin"
    end
  end
end
```